# DI with multiple intantiations of injected class

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-imagine

I'm using the [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) library for some image live editing and am running up against a wall understanding how to decouple classes that I might need to build multiple instances of dynamically.

***Contrived Example***

```
namespace App;

use Imagine\Image\{ Point, ImagineInterface };
use Imagine\Image\Palette\PaletteInterface;

class Image 
{
    protected $imagine;
    protected $palette;

    public function __construct(ImagineInterface $imagine, PaletteInterface $palette)
    {
        $this->imagine = $imagine;
        $this->palette = $palette;
    }

    public function buildImage($args)
    {
        $image = $this->imagine->open('some/file/path');
        $font = $this->imagine->font('some/font/path', 20, $this->palette->color('#000'));

        /* how to inject these when x/y are dynamically set? */
        $point1 = new Point($args['x1'], $args['y1']);
        $point2 = new Point($args['x2'], $args['y2']);

        $image->draw()->text('example one', $font, $point1);
        $image->draw()->text('example one', $font, $point2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best answer here, but no one has chimed in so I'm going to go with it. I created a factory class that is injected into the image class that takes arguments and returns a new instance of the Imagine Point class like so:

### Factory

```
namespace App\Image;

use Imagine\Image\Point;

class PointFactory
{
    public function create($x, $y)
    {
        return new Point($x, $y);
    }
}
```

### Image

```
namespace App;

use Imagine\Image\ImagineInterface;
use Imagine\Image\Palette\PaletteInterface;
use App\Image\PointFactory;

class Image 
{
    protected $imagine;
    protected $palette;

    public function __construct(ImagineInterface $imagine, PaletteInterface $palette, PointFactory $point)
    {
        $this->imagine = $imagine;
        $this->palette = $palette;
        $this->pointFactory = $point;
    }

    public function buildImage($args)
    {
        $image = $this->imagine->open('some/file/path');
        $font = $this->imagine->font('some/font/path', 20, $this->palette->color('#000'));

        /* how to inject these when x/y are dynamically set? */
        $point1 = $this->pointFactory->create($args['x1'], $args['y1']);
        $point2 = $this->pointFactory->create($args['x2'], $args['y2']);

        $image->draw()->text('example one', $font, $point1);
        $image->draw()->text('example one', $font, $point2);
    }
}
```

Now to test I create a mock of the factory and pass it in.